# Html page pre processor

Tags: clojure, preprocessor

I am looking around to find an html page processor to use with Clojure. Something like [jspp](http://www.jspp.io).

I've found [hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup) but I don't think it's written to be used as a preprocessor, for more complex pages I believe it would be difficult to code in the way it's meant to (for other things I think it's great).

Do you have something to suggest?

I was thinking about using jsps and coding something myself (.clj ends up in .class, so I think it's possible), but I'm leaving this as my last choice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [Fleet](https://github.com/Flamefork/fleet) interesting. Other templating tools are listed [here](http://www.glenstampoultzis.net/blog/clojure-web-infrastructure/) under *Templating*.